# understanding an expression: selection from list

Tags: dart

I have come across at this statement, and as a newby at dart, I cant figure out how it works, and how exactly does it selection from the List, please help!

```
var playersL=players.map<Player>((String _playerID) =>
            store.state.players.players.firstWhere((Player _player) => _player?.id == _playerID)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are doing with `playersL`, it is not going to work as expected since the expression returns a `Iterable<Player>`. I guess the `L` means you want a `List` so you should put a `toList()` at the end:

```dart
  var playersL = players
      .map<Player>((String _playerID) => store.state.players.players
          .firstWhere((Player _player) => _player?.id == _playerID))
      .toList();
```

But what the code are doing is the following:

1. Go though `players` (which I guess are `List<String>` and convert each `String` into a `Player` object.
2. To do so, we check (for each `String`), `store.state.players.players` (which I guess are `List<Player>`, and finds the first `Player` object which have an `id` which the same as the `String` coming from `players`.